# How to encrypt a key correctly? _ FLUTTER

Tags: flutter, dart, encryption, mobile

I am trying to implement private key encryption within my application.
However, this key that I have to encrypt is of the List  type and when I try to encrypt I get the following error:

```
Expected a value of type 'String', but got one of type 'List <int>'
```

how can I encrypt my key of type List  correctly without getting errors so that I can later pass the parameter as type Uint8List to my method:

```
AccountEntity.account (account, Uint8List.fromList (privateKey));
```

this is my code:

```
var privateKey = await account.keyPair.extractPrivateKeyBytes();
      privateKey = AesEncryptionDecryption
        .encryptKey(
        privateKey).bytes ;


    final entity =
        AccountEntity.account(account, Uint8List.fromList(privateKey));
```

while this is the class which contains the encryption methods, as API I used encrypt: ^ 5.0.1 from pubdev :

```
class AesEncryptionDecryption{
  static final key = encrypt.Key.fromLength(32);
  static final iv = encrypt.IV.fromLength(16);
  static final encrypter = encrypt.Encrypter(encrypt.AES(key));

  static encryptAES(text) {
    final encrypted = encrypter.encrypt(text, iv: iv);
    return encrypted;
  }

static encryptKey(text) {
    final encrypted = encrypter.encryptBytes(text, iv: iv);
    return encrypted as List<int>;
  }

  static String decryptAES(String base64Text) {
    print(base64Text);
    String decrypted = encrypter.decrypt(
      Encrypted.fromBase64(base64Text),
      iv: iv,
    );
    print(decrypted);
    return decrypted;
  }
```

does anyone know how to help me? thank you very much

Comment: If the data to be encrypted is available as `List<int>` you should use [`encryptBytes()`](https://pub.dev/documentation/encrypt/latest/encrypt/Encrypter/encryptBytes.html) instead of [`encrypt()`](https://pub.dev/documentation/encrypt/latest/encrypt/Encrypter/encrypt.html).

Comment: can u show me how in my code?

Comment: Simply replace `encrypter.encrypt()` by `encrypter.encryptBytes()`.

Comment: i get this error : Expected a value of type 'List<int>', but got one of type 'Encrypted'

Comment: can you answer me properly and be more specific?

Comment: What happens if you replace `join('')` with `bytes` and pass this _directly_ to `account()` in the 2nd parameter?

Comment: I changed the text above, I cannot directly assign the value otherwise it gives me an error in compiling like:
The argument type 'List <int>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Uint8List'.
I cannot change the type of the parameter because it must be of type Uint8List

Comment: I always get the same error: Expected a value of type 'List<int>', but got one of type 'Encrypted'

Comment: In `encryptKey()`, remove the cast `as List<int>` to return an `Encrypted` object so that the `bytes` property is available. This will give you the ciphertext as a `Uint8List`.

Comment: I don't understand why you want to receive the encrypted key as Uint8List and not as base64 encoded string, as your decryption function accepts a base64 string only ??

Comment: @MichaelFehr - Probably because the ciphertext is passed to the `account()` method and it expects a `Uint8List`.

Comment: Note that your key and IV consist of 0x00 values only. For testing purposes this is enough, but beyond that a random key should be used for security reasons (generated directly with a CSPRNG or derived from a password and a random salt with a key derivation function like PBKDF2). For a given key, a random IV should be generated for each encryption.